# Copy to the clipboard from extension context menu without using `scripting` or `content_scripts`?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Background: I would like to write an extension, where right-clicking on the extension icon and clicking on a context menu item copies something to the clipboard.

But I also want to avoid using the `scripting` permission or injecting `content_scripts` in the `manifest.json`, because some corporate environments don't allow it (for good reason).

But how can I copy to the clipboard from a `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` handler if I don't use `scripting` or `content_scripts`? Neither `document.execCommand` nor `navigator.clipboard.write` are available in background scripts (where both `document` and `navigator.clipboard` are undefined) and there is no page to send a message to, since the `action.default_popup` pages cannot be opened from background scripts and I don't want to use content injection.

Any ideas?

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks. This is nothing short of fantastic! If you'd care to convert this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cookbook.offscreen-clipboard-write](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.offscreen-clipboard-write) example is a working full example of using [chrome.offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). The essense is that offscreen was created for exactly this kind of purpose.

Here is a summary, but do see the two above links for more details:

First you add `"offscreen"` to the permissions in `manifest.json`.

Then in `background.js`:

```js
// This could also be chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener()
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL('offscreen.html'),
    reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.CLIPBOARD],
    justification: 'Need to copy data to the clipboard',
  });
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'copy-data-to-clipboard',
    target: 'offscreen-doc',
    data: 'put this string on the clipboard'
  });
});
```

`offscreen.html` has:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<script src="offscreen.js"></script>
```

And `offscreen.js`:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessages);

async function handleMessages(message) {
  if (message.target !== 'offscreen-doc') {
    return;
  }

  switch (message.type) {
    case 'copy-data-to-clipboard':
      handleClipboardWrite(message.data);
      break;
    default:
      console.warn(`Unexpected message type received: '${message.type}'.`);
  }
}

const textEl = document.querySelector('#text');

async function handleClipboardWrite(data) {
  try {
    if (typeof data !== 'string') {
      throw new TypeError(
        `Value provided must be a 'string', got '${typeof data}'.`
      );
    }

    textEl.value = data;
    textEl.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  } finally {
    window.close();
  }
}
```