# In my own chrome extension how do I copy active tab's URL to Clipboard?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I wrote a simple chrome extension that's supposed to access the active tab and copy it's url into clipboard. I can't get it to access clipboard.

Here's what I scrubbled so far

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    if (command === "copyURL") {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
        var currentTab = tabs[0];
        var url = currentTab.url;
        
        copyToClipboard(url);
    });
    }
});

function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var copyTextArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    copyTextArea.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(copyTextArea);
    copyTextArea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(copyTextArea);
}
```

This throws *document is not defined* error

[document is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSGu2.png)

I also tried this (which works fine when in Tampermonkey userscript)

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    if (tab.url) {
        console.log('URL: ', tab.url);
        console.log(navigator.clipboard);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(tab.url).then(() => {
            console.log('URL copied to clipboard');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error('Failed to copy URL: ', err);
        });
    }
});
```

It acts more weirdly: it says that `writeText` (same as `write`) doesn't even exist

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "URL Copier",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "clipboardWrite"
    ],
    "commands": {
        "copyURL": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+K"
            },
            "description": "Copy current tab's URL"
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

And the most frustrating part of it is, that **it works fine when manifest version is 2**, but ver.2 is obsolete and deprecated (2023). So i'm trying to move to ver. 3

upd. This answer here:
[Copy to the clipboard from extension context menu without using `scripting` or `content_scripts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977797/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-extension-context-menu-without-using-scripting-or)
doesn't quite suit me since `document.execCommand` is deprecated, but the Internet and *wherever-GPTs* seem to only know this obsolete method. I on the other side need a workaround, which figures out to come down to only `navigator` and nothing else